# Lock user in SQL Server using MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to lock a user in the database AspNetUsers when clicking on the button 'lock'

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LockUser(string Id)
        {
            var us = UserManager.FindById(Id);
        UserManager.FindById(Id).LockoutEnabled = true;
        UserManager.FindById(Id).LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2);
            UserManager.UpdateAsync(us);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This is my view:

```
<td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("LockUser", "Admin", new { id = x.Id }))
                {
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Lock" />
                }
            </td>
```

I have enabled the lock in my accountcontroller (true), I don't get a error while clicking it, nor does anything happens.

Comment: @freshbm I've edited the post as I did not use the string Id, but now I do, still won't lock the account.

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldn't you be using the variable `us` for the `LockoutEnabled` and `LockoutEndDateUtc` commands?

Comment: Added it into my posts, still no success whatsoever @DanBracuk

Answer (score 0):

You were making a copy of the non-locked user, updating the global user to be locked and then replacing the global user with your non-locked copy.

This will work better and make more sense.

```
public ActionResult LockUser(string Id)
{
  var us = UserManager.FindById(Id);
  us.LockoutEnabled = true;
  us.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2);
  UserManager.UpdateAsync(us);
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: User is still not locked, tested it and in the db it still says 'null' in the LockoutEndDateUtc column